# How to extend text selection across text blocks in a UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, paragraph

My app has a bunch of paragraphs which are compared together. This is implemented using a generic `ItemsRepeater` that creates as many `Grid` elements as there are paragraphs. Inside each grid is a `TextBlock` with the paragraph number, and a `RichTextBlock` that contains the paragraph. The hierarchy is therefore like this:

```
   <ItemsRepeater>
      <Grid>
         <TextBlock />
         <RichTextBlock></RichTextBlock/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid>
         ...
      </Grid>
      <Grid>
         ...
      </Grid>
   </ItemsRepeater>
```

This results in a text selection as follows:

[image: text selection of grid]

Only one `RichTextBlock` can be selected at a time. However, I would like to allow text selection of all paragraphs of the `ItemsRepeater`. How is that possible?

**Edit**

I'm open to other approaches. I've tried manually filling in a `StackPanel` or `RichTextBlock` with items. That's not a problem. However, because the numbered paragraphs need to align, I need to be able to set their height to match each other. From what I can find, only elements that derive from `FrameworkElement` have the `ActualHeight` and `Height` properties I need for that. However, `FrameworkElement`s like `TextBlock` and `RichTextBlock` also do not allow multiple selection, which is the problem I'm trying to solve in the first place. Someone [posted a response to a similar question about WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978206/how-to-get-the-height-of-the-run-or-paragraph), but it uses a strange solution I don't think applies.

So the question could also be framed as: how is it possible to find and set the height of a `Run` within a `TextBlock` or `RichTextBlock`? Using that idea, it was impossible to [get/set the run height inside a paragraph.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573045/get-set-height-of-run-inside-a-paragraph-in-uwp) I'm not bound to using `ItemsRepeater`, but that has also not yielded a useful result. I'm seeking to avoid resorting to HTML/Javascript for this.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Have you tried using `<Run></Run>`?

Comment: Text selection can only select content within the current text control and cannot select text across controls. If you want to achieve the effect, you need to put all the paragraphs in a richTextBlock. You could try to fill the RichTextBlock with text classes under the Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents namespace(e.g. Run, Paragraph etc.).

Comment: @Muzib I did that in the past. The only issue is that the paragraphs in each column would end up being at a different height, instead of being flush. Guess I'll have to measure the height of each paragraph and make them equal.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Unfortunately, "A value of type `ItemsRepeater' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'BlockCollection'."

Comment: The whole thing is frustrating, because UWP omits to derive `Run`, `Span`, `LineBreak`, or any other relevant element that can go inside a `TextBlock` or `RichTextBlock` from `FrameworkElement`, which means that the `ActualHeight` cannot be found, and the `Height` cannot be set. However, multiple `TextBlock`s or `RichTextBlock`s cannot be selected between as desired.

Comment: If you want to use RichTextBlock, then you can't use ItemsRepeat at the same time. You need to manually render.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT That's fine, and as explained in my edit, I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: However, there is no way to calculate the height of a Run.

Comment: Is the end goal to use the mouse to make a selection regardless of paragraphs when texts are displayed as paragraphs? (Inverted background and font color as selected)

Comment: @ConnorPark Basically, yes, that's the goal. But the paragraphs also have to be aligned across columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP does not expose enough APIs for you to do that. I have worked on a similar issue with RichEditBox on UWP and there is no good solution that I have found. But if you really want to, there are two main approaches to achieve that:

1. Implementing the selection yourself by sniffing the mouse events and render the selection on top of the controls. There are so many corner cases, specially if you want to have a proper accessibility tree for the control that you are building.
2. Alternatively, you can create a WinRT C++ project where you would have access to more APIs, build a control and render it onto a canvas that is created with your C#/Xaml app.

The good news is that you are not permitting people to edit (RichTextEdit) and it is just view (RichTextBlock) so you do not have to worry about the automatic corrections, [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method), Url detection, etc.

**Edit**: Originally I mentioned WinRT C++, but I meant C++/CX. It might work with WinRT too, but I have not tried.

Comment: Where's the documentation for building a control in RT and rendering it in the app?

Comment: You could see how you can create a C++/WinRT control [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-windows-runtime-component-in-cpp-and-calling-it-from-javascript-or-csharp).