# Get/set height of Run inside a paragraph in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to add multiple `Run` elements to a `TextBlock`. Each `Run` paragraph **must** be within the same `TextBlock` (to allow for selecting multiple paragraphs). However, *I also need to find the height of each `Run`, and set the height* if necessary.

Because `Run` does not inherit from `FrameworkElement`, `Height` and `ActualHeight` are not available properties. On the other hand, `Run` only allows children that can go in an `InlineCollection` (which does not include anything inheriting from `FrameworkElement`). This makes finding and setting the height of any child of a `Run` (or `TextBlock`, for that matter) impossible.

Is there a way to find and set the height of text elements inside a `TextBlock`?

As a note, I'd much rather use straight XAML/C# for its speed than have to tag on HTML/JavaScript just because XAML doesn't let one do something obvious (select multiple paragraphs with the cursor). It has also been suggested to use line heights or font size, but these don't achieve the same design effect.

Answer (score 0):

The height of `Run` is determined by `FontSize` and 1/2 `LineHeight`.

Although `Run` does not provide a `Height` like property to set its height, you can modify `Run`'s height in disguise by modifying `Run.FontSize` or `TextBlock.LineHeight`.

But for text wrapping, calculating the height of a single Run is not easy. We must also consider `FontFamily` (because monospace fonts and non-monospace fonts behave differently under the same font size).

If an article has multiple paragraphs, you can consider using multiple `TextBlock`s to calculate the height of each paragraph individually.

If you want to select text across controls, you can also consider converting the text to HTML and using `WebView` for display.

Best regards.

Comment: So there's no way to do this other than converting to HTML? Seems like an obvious solution is missing here...

Calculating the number of lines from the font size and character width may work in a pinch I suppose, but using the line height setting would change the leading at every couple of paragraphs. Not good design.

Comment: Hi, At present, the classes in the `TextDoucment` namespace do not provide related APIs to calculate the rendering height. The inability to select text across controls is also determined by the internal rendering mechanism. You can consider other methods, such as `HTML` or `RichTextBlock`

Comment: Hi, At present, the classes in the `TextDoucment` namespace do not provide related APIs to calculate the rendering height. The inability to select text across controls is also determined by the internal rendering mechanism. You can consider other methods, such as `HTML` or `RichTextBlock`

Comment: Is there something different with `RichTextBlock`? Because when I tried, the same problem occurred as in `TextBlock`.

Comment: Hi, When you use `TextBlock` in `InlineUIContainer`, you also cannot select text across controls. However, `RichTextBlock` can combine multiple text display types (such as `Paragraph`, `Run`, `Italic`, etc.). By combining them, you can achieve multiple text effects and also select text. But correspondingly, this requires you to write your own rendering method based on the text format passed in.

Comment: I understand, but it's also necessary for me to get and set the height of the `Paragraph`, `Run`, etc., which is not possible.

Comment: If you don't mind text rendering through C # code, you can try to use `Win2D.UWP`. `CanvasTextLayout` provides richer text settings. This is the relevant [document](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm).